# Trying to combine href attribute and location.search

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I would like to add a search query result to all subsequent page URL's that a visitor clicks on my site. However when a person on my page called "directions.html" clicks on the "**About Us**" link it comes up as:

http://justanexample.com/**directions**.html?guest#

The problem is that the link is going to directions.html and not about.html?  Does anyone know what is causing that?

Javascript

```
$("#aboutHtml").attr("href", "about.html" + location.search);
```

HTML

```
<a id="aboutHTML" href="#">About Us</a>
```

Comment: How is your Javascript retaining location.search between calls? Have you tried using alert to see if it's still the value you think it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your jQuery code runs after the links load.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#aboutHTML").attr("href", "about.html" + location.search);
});
```

Comment: This seems like a likely reason that you'd end up on directions.html rather than about.html, but I think there are other problems here as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a id="aboutHTML" onclick="newLocation();">About Us</a>

<script>
    function newLocation(){
      window.location = 'about.html'+ location.search;
    }
</script>
```